# How does the shift "1<<i" work in Python?

Tags: python

I have the following code in Python:

```
for i in range(4):
  if self.start == self.corners[i]:
    self.visitedCorners += (1 << i)
```

I'm working with co-ordinates. `self.start` and `self.corners` are co-ordinates.

So with the code on the top I want to check whether the start is a corner.
If the start is the same of a corner, I do that shift. But, how does that shift work?

I don't want any other code; I just want to understand *this* code.

Comment: https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Logical_shift

Comment: It is equivalent to a power of 2 (2 to the power of i+1).  Welcome to binary. You'll see lots of binary stuff in software development. 1,2,4,8,16,32...

Comment: *How does the shift “1<<i” work in Python?*: The same as in other languages.... (sorry, couldn't resist ;)).

Comment: @FelixKling: You mean like in C++ in `cout << "Hello World!"`? :P

Comment: Just as a side note, the `+=` will give you problems if you visit any corner more than once.  You probably want `|=`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All that `1 << i` does is produce the number with the `i`-th least significant bit set to `1` and all other bits set to `0`:

```
>>> for i in range(4): print bin(1 << i)
... 
0b1
0b10
0b100
0b1000
```

In the code, `self.visitedCorners` is a bit mask, where the four least significant bits correspond to the four corners. Each iteration of the `for i` loop sets the corresponding bit in `self.visitedCorners` to `1` (provided the `if` condition holds).

Comment: +1. Although without context the last line would have to be `self.visitedCorners |= (1 << i)` to ensure a correctly working bit-mask.

Comment: Another way to say it is that `1<<i` is the same as `2**i`. And in general, `x<<i` is the same as `x*(2**i)`. The shift operator is just way more efficient (and special cased to handle negatives in a bitwise manner)